# shm_open call for ios7 now results in operation not permitted during O_CREAT (EPERM)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipc, ios7, shared-memory

I maintain the shared memory section of an iOS application that worked perfectly until the latest release. The code no longer allows me to perform an O_CREAT to initialize a shared memory segment.

The code that appears to have lost functionality is similar to this:

```
int shm_fd;
if ((shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_PATH, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)) < 0){
    /** Handle failure  */
} else {
    /** Handle Success  */
}
```

This code snippet worked great until recently. Now it fails with errno set to EPERM.

If it helps at all, it still works perfectly in the simulator.

Has anyone else lost this ability as well? Any way to solve this?

**EDIT 1:** If it is deemed impossible to use my old method, I am wondering what I can do to simulate the same functionality. It is a source of shared data between multiple apps. The data is able to viewed and modified by all the apps that know about it.

**EDIT 2:** According to the [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/889012), IPC has been crippled in the newest release. Bug reports have been filed as it also affects intra-process communication. Hopefully this will be fixed but in the meantime I will be looking for a way to replicate the functionality.

Comment: If you tell us what you need the shared memory segment for, people can probably suggest an alternative.

Comment: Edited the question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long period of research we gave up on salvaging our old method of IPC. Our workaround is as follows:

In order to share information between our app-suite we had decided to utilize the iOS Keychain.

To make it even easier on us, we discovered someone had already wrapped all the keychain functionality into a package that was much easier to use [here](https://github.com/reidmain/FDKeychain).

This allows us to send our data between apps as long as the apps have the same app-identifier.

Not ideal, but it got the job done for us.

Answer (score 0):

Private, named UIPasteboard is one alternative. It's much slower than shared memory, but probably faster than the keychain.